# Expresso Store checkout and custom field based on entry ID

Tags: expresso-store, channel-entries, checkout, entryid

Based on a [documentation](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#entry_id) my code looks like (short version):

```
{exp:store:checkout channel="products" form_class="form-horizontal"}
            {items}
                TEST 1
            {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                TEST 2
            {/exp:channel:entries}
            {/items}
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

`TEST 2` message is not displayed at all.

Any clue what is going on?

Thanks

PS.
It looks like Expresso Store parsing bug. Similar issue described [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5575/cannot-retrieve-custom-fields-inside-expstorecheckout-tag)

PS.2

I have wipe out whole cart/index template and put just those lines:

```
TEST:

    {exp:channel:entries channel="products" entry_id="230" dynamic="no"}
    Entry id image:                         
    {product_image limit="1"}
    <img src="{product_image:image}" alt="{product_image:title}" class="img-responsive"></a>
    {/product_image}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

And what I'm getting is only a text `TEST:` nothing else. Product with an entry ID 230 exists in the products channel.

Comment: Please specify what's in TEST 2.
Also try to hard-code an actual entry_id in the entry_id="" variable for debug purposes.

Comment: `TEST 2` can be straight text which is not displayed anyway.

Comment: have you tried adding parse="inward" on the exp channel entries tag?

Comment: Still same problem. It looks like no matter what what is between `{exp:channel:entries channel="products" entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1"}` and `{/exp:channel:entries}` is not going to be processed.

Comment: Do your products have a status other then Open assigned to them?

Comment: @JustinLong yes, they can have different status than Open

Comment: Try adding `status="not closed" to your channel entries tag

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Justin Long tips I have got it to work. Example code looks like:

```
    {exp:store:checkout form_class="form-horizontal"}

                {items}
                    *Some code here*
                     {exp:channel:entries channel="products" status="not closed" dynamic="no" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                      *Custom field code here*
                      {/exp:channel:entries}
                {/items}

{/exp:store:checkout}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an embed to deal with parsing issues

```
{items}
    {embed="_embeds/list" id="{entry_id}"}
{/items}
```

In the embedded template set:

```
{exp:channel:entries limit="1" dynamic="off" entry_id="{embed:id}" }
    TEST 2
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Since the {entry_id} in your loop needs to be the one you are actually passing to the embed, then change to {embed:id}.

Comment: I have tried that one too  - no luck. Looks like a serious Store bug in parsing.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to do that with `stash`?